# CKEditor select as a single element

Tags: html, ckeditor, selection

I'd like to have an element in a CKEditor editable div be treated like an input for the purposes of mouse selection. The element is a `span` but I want to make it so that a user cannot select part of its content along with content outside of it. For instance, if it has the following DOM:

```
Foo <span>gobbledigook</span> bar
```

the user should be able to select within the span, within "Foo" or "bar", or starting from "Foo" and extending into "bar", but no select from "Foo" into the span content. For these purposes, `<span>` should be treated like an `<input />` (see [this jsbin](https://jsbin.com/mifihopaje/edit?html,js,output) on how that works).

The span is actually using CKEditor's `widget` plugin, which appears to satisfy the other direction (that is, you can select within the span, but dragging from within the span to outside the span doesn't extend the selection outside the span). It's just the outside -> inside that's not working.

Answer (score 0):

I have a workaround for this:

```
editor.widgets.on("checkSelection", function(event) {
        var range = editor.getSelection().getRanges()[0];

        var start = range.startContainer;
        var end = range.endContainer;

        // widgetRepository.getByElement() chokes if the argument is a text node
        if (start.type === CKEditor.NODE_TEXT) {
            start = start.getParent();
        }

        if (end.type === CKEditor.NODE_TEXT) {
            end = end.getParent();
        }

        var endWidget = editor.widgets.getByElement(end);

        if (
            // We only worry about selecting from outside of a widget to the inside of one
            endWidget
            // Selection ends inside a widget and the start is not in a widget *or* is within a different widget
            && editor.widgets.getByElement(start) !== endWidget
        ) {
            range.setEndBefore(endWidget.wrapper);
            range.select();
        }
    });
```

Basically, if I detect that a selection is ending within a widget that it didn't start in, I move the end to right before the widget wrapper.